# How to resize the select menu according to the height of selected option?

Tags: html, css, sass, html-select

I have a select menu, each options has different length. How can I change the height of the select menu according to the height of selected option? The width of the select menu should be the same.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

select {
  padding: 30px, 30px, 0, 0;
  max-width: 280px;
  min-width: 140px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 32px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
    @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      max-width: 320px;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
      max-width: 180px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <select> 
    <option value="first">First Value First Value First Value First Value First Value First Value</option> 
    <option value="second" selected>Second Value Second Value Second Value Second Value</option>
    <option value="third">Third Value Third Value Third Value Third Value</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Link to the [CodePen](https://codepen.io/kuzminadya/pen/KBozbz)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want the select box to be as wide as the widest sub option?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The width of the select menu should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Well this can easily be implemented if you use some jquery :P

```js
function function1()
{
    var val = document.getElementById("ID1").value;
    console.log(val);
    if (val == "first")
 {
  $("#ID1").css( {"height": "20px"} );
 }
 else if (val == "second")
 {
  $("#ID1").css( {"height": "50px"} );
 }
 else if (val == "third")
 {
  $("#ID1").css( {"height": "100px"} );
 }
}
```

```css
select{
   height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select Id="ID1" onchange="function1()"> 
      <option value="first">First Value First Value First Value First Value First Value First Value</option> 
      <option value="second" selected>Second Value Second Value Second Value Second Value</option>
      <option value="third">Third Value Third Value Third Value Third Value</option>
 </select>
```

don't forget to add an id to your select as well as call the function1() onchange.

```
<select Id="ID1" onchange="function1()">
```